# Executing two functions in an excel sheet?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have this simple function

```
=IF(ISBLANK(H2)=TRUE,0,VLOOKUP(H2,$Q$3:$R$14,2,FALSE) J2=3)
```

I want `J2` to equal **3** and have it look-up on the table on false, is it possible or will I need to have another table setup for this?

Comment: I wrote an answer but realised I didn't understand what yoiu were trying to achieve. It isn't clear for me. Perhaps others might understand.

Comment: A formula can only return a value to the cell where it's entered - it can't set a value in another cell

Comment: I wanted the first cell to modify another so that way depending on how many cells are "active" it would determine how much would be in J2. I just got around this by setting J2 based on which cells are blank or not with a sumsif but maybe there's a better way. Basically was looking for the equiv of if (1==1) { dothis; alsodothis; }

Answer (score 0):

You need to make two formulas - one for vlookup, one for J2:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(H2)=TRUE,0,VLOOKUP(H2,$Q$3:$R$14,2,FALSE))
=IF(ISBLANK(H2)=TRUE,0,3)
```

Place second formula to J2 cell.